# How archive many types of file in one .dat file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to develop an application to store **meeting files**.

**This application should not use the database**. Initially the data should be archived in a single file, such as a **DAT**. Must possess the ability to store **images**, **videos** and **audio**. All this adding **security** methods and if possible **encryption**.

Anyone know tell me technology to develop this storage or examples?

Any help will be very welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One technology - ZIP, includes compression, security and encryption and can contain multiple files of virtually any type.

Added bonus, you can just rename the `file.zip` to `file.dat`!

Check out DotNetZip for a .NET based zipping library - http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is simple and practical idea, and with enough content available. The only drawback is that possibly in order to speed up will I need to save to multiple files. Thanks

Comment: It should be pretty quick if you drop the compression level to something small, or completely off.